# adapt bootstrap3 grid size to my needs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have to make a very simple responsive website, thinking to use Bootstrap 3. First time playing around...

All content is maximum width 960px, very simple, just header (960px), a main interface (630px) and a sidebar (320px), with an space of 10px between both.

When we are on small devices, the sidebar should be stacked under main interface.

So, I know that Bootstrap3 accepts 12 grids, each grid maximum 70px + max 30px gutter (dividing each grid).

If I apply the code below...

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h1>my Header, should be 960px</h1>            
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8 ">This should be 630px</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">This should be 320px</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Of course I allways get a 1170px in all content (8+4=12 grids) in desktop devices.

How can I do to make the content 960px width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your rows in a fixed width container like..

```
.container-fixed {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 960px;
}
```

The `row` and `col-*` will still work responsively inside the fixed width container.

Here's a working demo: http://bootply.com/96043